# How can I configure Rails 3.0.7 host for links for development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer, host

Whenever I send out emails in development mode, it does not put the localhost:3000 in the url. Is there any way I can configure this site-wide?

I have tried the following:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

inside of an initializer, but it has no effect.

I have also tried this in 'development.rb':

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'localhost:3000'}
```

Help?

Comment: Could you add an example of your Mailer views? Just to check that you don't use `xxx_path` or other similar mistakes.

Comment: @Marcel Jackwerth: I am using xxx_path. What do I need to use? I've been using xxx_path for everything on the site so far... is that bad?

Comment: nope.. you should always use xxx_url in mailer views and anything that is shared with the external world. Refer to the rails guides for the difference between _path and _url

Comment: You should put that as the answer so i can checkmark you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(as in the comments to the question, so that the question can be answered)

Make sure you use the `_url` helpers in your Mailer views, because `_path` will only output relative urls (i.e. without the hostname).